# add struct variable/name to the left of :=

Tags: go

How to shorten this code

```
access_log, err := os.OpenFile("log/access.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0660);
w.access_log = access_log
```

To something like this

```
w.access_log, err := os.OpenFile("log/access.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0660);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign (`=`), not declare (`:=`):

```
var error
w.access_log, err = os.OpenFile("log/access.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0660);
```

`:=` is for [Short Variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), and `w.access_log` is already declared (in `w` struct)

It is discussed in [issue 6842](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6842).